# How can i update a model field when another model field changes in mongoDb

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to make the postSchema username get updated whenever userSchema username changes

```
//This is the PostSchema

const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    username: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: false,
    },
    profileDp: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
})
```

```
//This is the user Schema

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    _id: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    username: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: false,
    },
    profilePic: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
```

So how do i create a relationship in the postSchema such that whenever userSchema username changes then the postSchema username should also change?

So far i've seen $set, ref or even populate() being recommended but i'm still unsure on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `pre-hooks` on the `UserSchema` while updating the username like below.

```
UserSchema.pre(["updateOne", "findOneAndUpdate", "findByIdAndUpdate", "updateMany" ], async function (next) {
    if(this.get("username")){
         let userDoc = await mongoose.model("user").findOne(this._conditions);
         await mongoose.model("post").updateOne({ username: userDoc.username },{
         username: this.get("username")
         });
    }
    next();
  }))
```

Check the above example, whenever your username update it will automatically update in post documents
For more clarification about `pre-hooks` visit this link https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html

Comment: I tried this and didn't work, I keep getting "internal server error", And the it's stopping the user object from updating.